# Hosting Jenkins

Tags: apache, tomcat, jenkins

What is the best way to run jenkins?

1. Jenkins as a standalone service
2. Jenkins behind apache alone
3. Jenkins behind apache-tomcat

And also why should I run Jenkins behind apache-tomcat?

please could somebody help me with these answers?

Comment: everything on top of the supplied java servlet container ( windstone ) is pretty much taste of the admin/developer only . Jenkins is a (java) buildserver, why should the hosting (web-)server be of great concern?

Answer (score 2):

Should consider three main aspects when taking this decision:

- Security
- Simplicity
- Load

The built-in [**Winstone** Servlet-Container](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Winstone) is great for small implementations of Jenkins,
especially if sitting behind the company's firewall, protected from internet attacks.
And it works out-of-the-box, of course.

**Apache-Tomcat** will require some setup, but will allow you to protect your
Jenkins site from attacks, if you plan to expose it to the world, [like Jenkins does](https://ci.jenkins-ci.org/).
It should also perform better under pressure, like when you have a big number of jobs to manage.

See here [How to setup Jenkins with **Tomcat** or other servlent-containers](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Containers).